# Deprecated ios Button api. ButtonConfiguration

Tags: ios, swift

I'm just trying to set `adjustsImageWhenDisabled = false`. I get a deprecation warning but can't find a simple solution. I can think of workarounds myself but this code `adjustsImageWhenDisabled = false` is just so simple and works.

My "image" is just an image made out of a color using `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext`. What I do now is that I override `isEnabled` and on `didSet` I set `backgroundColor` if disabled otherwise I use `setBackgroundImage(for:)` so that I get the highlighted effect when enabled.

And why does it not just work to use `setBackgroundImage(for:.disabled)`?

Answer (score 0):

Can you not try and set `.disabled` by setting the background image of the image.

`image.setBackgroundImage(disabledImage, for: .disabled)`

Comment: That didn't work :(.
I have an extension func, setBackgroundColor which will create an image from a color so I called image.setBackgroundColor(color, for .disabled) . That didn't work.
I use the same func for setting for the .normal and .highlighted state and they work.
Even if I don't set the .highlighted state, I still get another color for disabled even though I've not set it.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the deprecated warning with message like *"This property is ignored when using UIButtonConfiguration..."* so, you can still use it with `UIButton` otherwise use the `configurationUpdateHandler` like below:

```
self.btn.configurationUpdateHandler = { button in
        switch button.state {
        case .disabled:
            button.imageView?.tintAdjustmentMode = .dimmed
            break
        default:
            button.imageView?.tintAdjustmentMode = .normal
            break
        }
    }
```

Comment: I did try exactly that. But it's far from what I what in both simplicity and behavior.